# Pyautogui.press() not working in Chrome Flash

Tags: google-chrome, flash, pyautogui

I am using the pyautogui library. When I call pyautogui.press(), it is not registering clicks inside the Chrome Flash player. How do I overcome this?

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('right')
```

This is the basic code I am using which worked for text editors and inside Chrome also, but not in flash player in chrome.

The website I am using this on is http://www.tetrisfriends.com/games/Sprint5P/game.php, where I want to automate the blocks' moves. Thanks.

Comment: Flash content in browser must have **focus** before it responds to keyboard or clicks. That means you must click somewhere on the game area first before anything... On your link, click something else that is not the game (eg: page background etc) & try to control the game (gives no response since not focused). To use clicks shouldn't it be `pyautogui.click(some X pos, some Y pos)`? After "clicking" that game position then maybe try to use keyboard "press"...

Comment: I did not try mouse clicks, but I have clearly checked keyboard presses by focussing in the game area many times. When I focussed the cursor in a text editor it works fine and registers the key presses but not in a flash player. When I focussed in the flash player the keystrokes are going into cmd from which the program is executed.

Comment: Did you now try a mouse click on the game before expecting to control via with keyboard? Flash Player is a **plugin** (like a separate program running in a layer inside the browser). Example of my point : (without using PyAutoGUI) just go to the game, start playing but then click on webpage background (the blue/white squares wallpaper), notice the pop up saying the game needs to be clicked to control it? Make sure your PyAutoGUI test is meeting that requirement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've posted, what is most likely happening is that the Flash game does not have focus. You can fix this by clicking on the Flash game itself. Note that the browser having focus may not be enough, you also have to click on the Flash app itself.